# Logical inconsistency in proof that limit of rational functions can be evaluated by direct substitution

Tags: calculus, limits, rational-functions

This is the problem that I am trying to prove without bringing up *continuity* since I won't learn about it for another 4 chapters. I've already proven that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$ for polynomial functions.

If $f$ is a rational function, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$, provided $c$ is in the domain of $f$.

This is my proof:

1. Since $f(x)$ is rational function, by definition $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$
   for some polynomial functions $p, q$, such that $q(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.
2. Since it is given that $c$ is in the domain of $f$ we can conclude that $q(c) \neq 0$.
3. Since $q$ is a polynomial function, we know that $\lim_{x \to c} q(x) = q(c)$. We also showed that $q(x) \neq 0$, thus it follows that $\lim_{x \to c} q(x) \neq 0$ as well.
4. From here
   $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)
   = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} =
       \frac{\lim_{x \to c} p(x)}
            {\lim_{x \to c} q(x)}
   = \frac{p(c)}{q(c)} =
       f(c) $

Chat GPT claims that I have a logical inconsistency in step 3, and I kind of get why, but not quite... Do I really need to reason about the neighborhood of $c$ if I know that $\lim_{x \to c} q(x) = q(c)$? Why can't I conclude that $\lim_{x \to c} q(x) \neq 0$?

Note: This is not for a class. I am in my late 30s studying on my own.

[Chat GPT pointing out problem with step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVnBd.png)

Comment: Don't use chatGPT to study math

Comment: Is Chat GPT incorrect in this case and why?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}q(x)\ne 0$ because $\lim_{x\to c}q(x)=g(c)$ and $g(c)\ne 0$.

Comment: See what happens if you ask Chat GPT to prove pi is irrational. Then ask it to prove pi is transcendental. You'll see some circular reasoning. Ask it to prove the theorems without circular reasoning it will just append "without circular reasoning" to its previous erroneous reasoning. "To prove pi is transcendental without using circular reasoning, ...<proceeds to prove using circular reasoning." It doesn't even understand the words.

Comment: Thank you all! That puts it in perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument looks fine to me. Please do not rely on ChatGPT for logical arguments. Language models are completely unable of logical reasoning. Unless you ask ChatGPT questions, where the answer can be found on the internet an abundant number of times, ChatGPT will just output something that sounds fitting in the current situation.

ChatGPT has learned, that saying "You made a mistake in Step 3" sounds like a plausible answer to any type of question about mathematical reasoning. It did not actually check your arguments.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my reasoning and clarifying!